# LinqToSql - Explicit construction of entity type '{0}' in query is not allowed

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I'm facing a very strange problem on two easy webapi methods:

I have lot of methods that are used to retrive masterdata from db.
They are all similars and they all read tables with same structures.

I really don't know why for example this method works:

## this works

```
[HttpGet]
//[Authorize]
[Route("offertsource/get")]
public IHttpActionResult api_MasterData_OffertSource_GET()
{
    var res = new List<mdOffertSource>();
    try
    {
        res = (from c in db.mdOffertSources.OrderBy(x => x.OffertSource)
               select new mdOffertSource() { idOffertSource = c.idOffertSource, Code = c.Code, OffertSource = c.OffertSource }).ToList();

        return Ok(res);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return BadRequest(e.Message);
    }
}
```

and this doesn't work:

## NOT working code

```
[HttpGet]
//[Authorize]
[Route("offertstatus/get")]
public IHttpActionResult api_MasterData_OffertStatus_GET()
{
     var res = new List<mdOffertStatus>();
     try
     {
         res = (from c in db.mdOffertStatus.OrderBy(x => x.intOrder).ThenBy(x => x.OffertStatus)
               select new mdOffertStatus() { idOffertStatus = c.idOffertStatus, Code = c.Code, OffertStatus = c.OffertStatus }).ToList();

        return Ok(res);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return BadRequest(e.Message);
    }
}
```

I have lot of methods similar to the first one working and only the second one below is not working.

If I test it, i get this error:

**Explicit construction of entity type 'XionDB.mdOffertStatus' in query is not allowed.**

I have already tried to remove the table mdOffertStatus from the dbml file and to add again it but I face the same problem...

This is very strange.

Thanks to support

Comment: I don't think so... The scenario is different...

Comment: @GiladGreen but the instantiation works in the first example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by deleting the dbml file and adding it again...

Before I tryied to remove and add again the table **mdOffertStatus** but nothing changed, dropping the dbml and adding it again fixed the problem.

May be there was some mess in the solution...
Thanks to support

Answer (score 1):

Your OfferSources table isn't empty, is it? That would cause the Select not to be called and avoid the error thrown in the second method.

(Would leave this as a comment but don't have enough points.)